# Drupal 8 Multisite sub-directory

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, drupal-8, multisite

Want to integrate in Drupal-8 (Multi-site in subdirectories)

Needed multi site like www.xyz.com , www.xyz.com/kolkata
www.xyz.com/bengaluru and www.xyz.com/kalyani

where xyz.com is a separate site, xyz.com/kolkata is separate site,
so as xyz.com/bengaluru and xyz.com/kalyani.

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: How to integrate Drupal-8 (Multi site in Sub directories like above example) ?